# cloud/datastore no buildable Go source files

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a project that I work on both at home and here at work. At home (my primary place of work on the project) the code is up and running fine. However, here at work after pulling down some updates. When I try to `go run app.go` or just do a `go get` or `go get -d` I'm seeing the following error.

> ../google.golang.org/cloud/datastore/save.go:25:2: no buildable Go
>   source files in $GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/type

I've gone into the $GOPATH/src and wiped all the source files from the other repos/packages and still get the error with the `go get` commands. Any insight would be mighty appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I've made a little progress but still having other issues now. Turns out I did not have protoc install and then I did not have the golang protobufs installed. I got those installed along with that was adding in the $GOPATH/bin to my $PATH. However, now the error has moved away from the cloud/datastore off to: package google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/type: no buildable Go source files in $GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/type

Comment: It would still be nice to know what is going on here but, what I wound up doing to get going was to rebuild a whole new environment. That is I created a whole new directory for my Go stuff. Updated my $GOPATH and other relevant $GO vars.  Created the src, bin, pkg directories, re-cloned my project into the src directory and magically go get -u ran without a hitch. MADDENING